# Which filter/hook to use for styling comments?

Tags: comments, css

I would like to create a plugin that modify the styling of the comments section. Given that some users may be using other plugin to replace the default commenting system (facebook, disqus, ...), what are my options? Is the `comments_template` filter/template a good place to start? Basically, I intend to "surround" the existing comments output with HTML code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the `comments_form` function that outputs the contact form has two actions that could be used to accomplish what you want.

```
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'wwm_comment_form_before' );

function wwm_comment_form_before() {
//output your opening html here
}

add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'wwm_comment_form_after' );

function wwm_comment_form_after() {
//output your closing html here
}
```

and that's a wrap :)